# LoRa to MQTT sensor data can't be read

Tags: programming

I'm trying to transfer data from a temperature sensor that is located outside my WiFi area. I have chosen LoRa technology between an ESP32 equipped with an SX1278 and a TTGO Lilygo LoRa.

So far everything works fine, but as soon as I try to publish the data via Mosquitto MQTT in order to have access to the home assistant, things are get worse. I use MQTT Explorer to view the exchanges with Mosquitto. I also monitor the data on the serial port.
Everything works correctly as long as I don't publish the temperature data. But from the moment I publish it after changing it to string to switch to MQTT, I have some problems:

- The serial port displays wrong values of the string  and scrolls continuously.
- The data sent to MQTT are well displayed, coherent with the serial port, but remain incoherent and the number of publications increase quickly.
- From a certain moment, things do not move anymore.

So I have at least two problems, and even though I looked at many examples, I have trouble understanding everything.

You will find attached the code loaded into the Lilygo receiver hoping that it will help solve my problem(s):

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <Streaming.h>
#include <Ticker.h>

#define OLED_SDA 21 // Attention: Les broches SDA et SCL de l'affichage OLED sont inversées sur le dessin de LilyGO et sur GitHub.
#define OLED_SCL 22 
#define OLED_RST 12 // Note: Le TTGO Lora32 v2 n'utilise pas le signal reset, mais la librairie Adafruit_SSD1306, oui.
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels

const int csPin = 18; // LoRa radio chip select-TTGO
const int resetPin = 23; // LoRa radio reset-TTGO
const int irqPin = 26; // change for your board; must be a hardware interrupt pin-TTGO
const int sckPin = 5; //-TTGO
const int misosPin = 19; //-TTGO
const int mosiPin = 27; //-TTGO
const char* ssid = "xxxxxx"; // Nom du wifi
const char* password = "xxxxxx"; // Mot de passe wifi

const char* mqtt_server = "xxx.xxx.x.xx"; // Adresse IP du brovker MQTT
const char* mqtt_username = "xxxxx"; // User MQTT
const char* mqtt_password = "xxxxxx"; // Password MQTT
const char* mqtt_topic = "ESP32/DS18B20/temp_piscine"; // Nom du topic MQTT envoyé par home assistant

char incoming ;
char msg[4];

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RST);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);

  // setup WiFi
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);

  //initialize OLED
  Wire.begin(OLED_SDA, OLED_SCL);
  if (!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3c, false, false)) { // Address 0x3C for 128x32
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
  }
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setCursor(0,0);
  display.print("LORA RECEIVER ");
  display.display();

  Serial.println("LoRa Receiver");

  // override the default CS, reset, and IRQ pins (optional)
    SPI.begin(sckPin, misosPin, mosiPin, csPin);
    LoRa.setPins(csPin, resetPin, irqPin); // set CS, reset, IRQ pin

  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }
}

//Fonction connexion au wifi appelé dans le setup 
void setup_wifi() {
  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  display.setCursor(0,0);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

//Fonction connexion au wifi appelé dans le setup 
void callback(char* topic, byte* message, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived on topic: ");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print(". Message: ");
  String messageTemp;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)message[i]);
    messageTemp += (char)message[i];
  }
  Serial.println();
}

//Fonction connexion au serveur Mqtt  dans le loop 
void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect("ESP8266Client", mqtt_username, mqtt_password)) {
      Serial.println("connected");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  client.loop();
  // try to parse packet
  int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) {
    // received a packet
    Serial.print("Received packet ");
    // read and print packet
    display.clearDisplay();
    display.setCursor(0,0);
    while (LoRa.available()) {
      incoming = ((char)LoRa.read());
      //Serial.print((char) LoRa.read());
      Serial.print(incoming);
      display.print(incoming);  
    }
    // print RSSI of packet
    Serial.print("' with RSSI ");
    Serial.println(LoRa.packetRssi());    
    //display.setCursor(0,0);
    display.print("' with RSSI ");
    display.println(LoRa.packetRssi());
    display.display();
  }
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  dtostrf(incoming, 6, 2, msg);
  Serial.print (msg);
  client.publish(mqtt_topic,msg,false);
  //client.publish(mqtt_topic,dtostrf(LoRa.packetRssi(),6,2,msg),false);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't see anything obviously wrong - what are the reported RAM usage values when the program is built ? It could certainly by that you are experiencing some kind of stack overflow, or memory corruption.

Answer (score 2):

Hello and thank you for your support. I finally found the problem, which was that using incoming needs to be stored in a buffer to be used as it was sent char by char. I also found the possibility to use `LoRa.readString()`, which allows a full string storage. I used after the function LoRaData.indexOf..., which allows to select specific parts of text with specific marks such as #, *, /, ...
Here is an example of the code used for those who could be interested.

```c
void loop() {
  client.loop();
// try to parse packet
  int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) 
{
    // received a packet
    Serial.println("Received packet ");
    // read and print packet
    display.clearDisplay();
    display.setCursor(0,0);
    while (LoRa.available()) //>0 retiré
    {
      String LoRaData = LoRa.readString();
      Serial.print(LoRaData);   
    // Get Text, temperature and end text : *Temp.piscine #21.56*C*
      int pos1 = LoRaData.indexOf('#');
      int pos2 = LoRaData.indexOf('*');
      Text = LoRaData.substring(0, pos1);
      temperature = LoRaData.substring(pos1 +1, pos2);
      End = LoRaData.substring(pos2+1, LoRaData.length());  
    }
    // print RSSI of packet
    Serial.print("' with RSSI ");
    Serial.println(LoRa.packetRssi());    
     display.print("temperature Piscine = ");
    display.print(temperature);
    display.print("°C");
    display.print("' with RSSI ");
    display.println(LoRa.packetRssi());
    display.display();
      }
}
```

I still need to work on it, but it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your `dtostrf(incoming, 6, 2, msg);`, you want to store a float that has a minimum width of 6, with 2-digit precision, you will need an array of at leat 9 bytes(plus NULL terminator) for a value like '12345.78', you only allow 4 bytes for your `msg[4];` which is definitely insufficient.

Even if your temperature is 32.45, it will still need an array of 6 for `msg`.